# opengl texture mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, texture-mapping

i have got a single texture working in my opengl project
the problem is it only lets me use one texture
i was wondering how i can change this so i can use multiple textures
maybe an array?
when i load in more than one bitmap image i can't seem to get it to work

this is the code i am using to create the texture

```
glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    Bitmap image;

    image.loadBMP ("TEXTURE1.bmp");
    glGenTextures(1, &m_TextureID);
    glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TextureID);

    glTexEnvf ( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE , GL_MODULATE);
    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, image.width, image.height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);
    glDisable (GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

can anybody point me in the right direction
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides calling [glGenTextures](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenTextures.xml) n times, you can do this :

```
const GLsizei n = 5;
GLuint textureIDs = new GLuint[ n ];
glGenTextures( n, textureIDs );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your stuck

```
GLuint num_textures = 5;
GLuint textures[num_textures];

glGenTextures(num_textures, textures);
```

:)